# Confirmation window on @picklist formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is it possible to add confirmation window on the @picklist window? That is, after clicking OK button, I want to prompt user to confirm the choice.

Comment: I think you will have to do that yourself, and wrap your `@picklist` in a `@while` loop or similar.

Comment: Would you be so kind and give an example through formula use or LS?

Comment: Are you familiar with @Prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@DoWhile(
    @PickList(...);
    n :=@Prompt([YesNo]; "Conformation"; "All Right?");
    n = 1;
)
```